# A question about groups of order $504=2^3\cdot 3^2 \cdot 7$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I was looking at past qualifying exams in algebra and came across the following problem which I can't solve.

> The problem asks to show that if a group $G$ of order $504=2^3\cdot 3^2 \cdot 7$ has a normal subgroup of order $2^3$, then it has at most $8$ Sylow $7$-subgroups.

Applying the Sylow theorems gives that the number of Sylow $7$-subgroups is either $1$, $8$, or $36$. So we only need to exclude the last possibility.
If $P$ is a  Sylow $7$-subgroup of $G$ and if $G$ has $36$ Sylow $7$-subgroups, then $N_G(P)$ has order $14$. I don't see what to do with that information though.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Sylow' Theorem implies that $G/N$ has a unique (and hence normal) Sylow $7$-subgroup, where $N$ is the normal subgroup of $G$ of order 8.

Comment: That only gives that $G$ has a normal subgroup, say $H$, of order $56$. The Frattini argument gives $G=N_G(Q)H$ so $G/H \cong N_G(Q) / N_H(Q)$ has order $3^2$, so $N_G(Q)$ does not have order $14$. Is that it?

Comment: Yes that's right  (is $P=Q$?)

Comment: Yes, sorry. I messed up the notation and can't edit now.

Comment: The order of $N_{G}(P)$ is at least $56$.

Answer (score 2):

Following Derek Holt's hint, consider the canonical epimorphism:
$$ G\to G/N $$

where $N$ is the unique Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$.

By correspondence theorem, we know that there is a **bijection** of subgroups in $G/N$ and subgroups in $G$ containing $N$.

Furthermore, Sylow theorems tell us that there is only **one** Sylow $7$-subgroup in $G/N$.

However, note that every Sylow $7$-subgroup $H$ in $G$ can be made into a subgroup of order $56$, namely $NH\supset N$ since $N$ is normal. Hence we conclude that $NH$ is a subgroup of order $56$ of $G$ containing $N$ for any Sylow $7$-subgroup $H$. Moreover, it is the **only** subgroup of order $56$ containing $N$.

Now we have $$NH_1=NH_2=NH_3=\cdots=NH_k$$
 where $H_i$ s are distinct Sylow $7$-subgroups, and we must have $k<10$, since $H_i\cap H_j=\{e\}$, the unit, if $i\ne j$ and there are at most $$ \left\lfloor\frac{56}{7-1} \right\rfloor=9 $$ possibilities.

As you have claimed that the only possibilities of numbers of subgroups of order $7 $ are $1,8$ and $36$ and we are through.